# How to list different OU in this command: Get-Mailbox -OrganizationalUnit

Tags: windows, powershell

How do I list different OUs in the command `Get-Mailbox -OrganizationalUnit`?

`Get-Mailbox -OrganizationalUnit OU1` works without issues.

I need to list other OU in this command like `-OrganizationalUnit OU1, OU2, ...` but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to accomplish this is to loop through a list of your OUs and send each of them to the Get-Mailbox command:

```
$OUs = "OU1","OU2","OU3"

Foreach ($OU in $OUs) {
   Get-Mailbox -OrganizationalUnit $OU
}
```